# ReactJS: Getting an error in array. Its saying "TypeError: Cannot read property 'handleDismiss' of undefined". Cant figure out why

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, list, react-native

For some reason I am getting an error after pressing my dismiss button. It says "TypeError: Cannot read property 'handleDismiss' of undefined". I have no idea whyt this is happening. Spent the whole day googling but to no avail

I tried to change the handlers and also to bind the button. Still same result of "TypeError: Cannot read property 'handleDismiss' of undefined"

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';


const basketballPlayers = [
  {id:1, name:"Stephen Curry", rating:97, position: "PG"},
  {id:2, name:"Kevin Durant", rating:85, position: "PF"},
  {id:3, name:"Klay Thompson", rating:80, position: "SG"},
  {id:4, name:"Vince Carter", rating:72, position: "SG"},
  {id:5, name:"Yao Ming", rating:99, position: "C"}
];

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state ={
      basketballPlayers: basketballPlayers
    }
  }

  handleDismiss=(id) =>{
    console.log(id);
  }

  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const searchTerm = e.target.elements.inputTerm.value;
    console.log("search term",searchTerm);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
      <h1>Basketball Players</h1>
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <input name="inputTerm"/>
        <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm">SEARCH</button>
      </form>
       {this.state.basketballPlayers.map(function(basketballPlayer) {
         return(
           <div key={basketballPlayer.id}>
             <p>{basketballPlayer.name}</p>
             <p>{basketballPlayer.rating}</p>
             <p>{basketballPlayer.position}</p>
             <button onClick={()=>this.handleDismiss(basketballPlayer.id)}>Dismiss</button>
             </div>
         );
       })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I just want my button to stop showing the error. I want to log the id number from each object onto the console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the context of parent 'this' changes inside map.

You can fix it by passing the current context 'this' to the map function as the second parameter OR use ES6 arrow function.

```
this.state.basketballPlayers.map(function(basketballPlayer) { ... }, this)
```

OR

```
this.state.basketballPlayers.map(basketballPlayer => { ... })
```

Answer (score 1):

In your map function, you create a new function, which will have its own `this`, you should instead use an anonymous function to use the parent `this`, similarly like how you did your onClick handler:

```
{this.state.basketballPlayers.map((basketballPlayer) => (
  <div key={basketballPlayer.id}>
    <p>{basketballPlayer.name}</p>
    <p>{basketballPlayer.rating}</p>
    <p>{basketballPlayer.position}</p>
    <button onClick={()=>this.handleDismiss(basketballPlayer.id)}>Dismiss</button>
  </div>
)}
```

Answer (score 0):

the map function is obfuscating the "this". Try to isolate the function before:

```
let { handleDismiss } = this
{this.state.basketballPlayers.map(function(basketballPlayer) {
     return(
       <div key={basketballPlayer.id}>
         <p>{basketballPlayer.name}</p>
         <p>{basketballPlayer.rating}</p>
         <p>{basketballPlayer.position}</p>
         <button onClick={()=>handleDismiss(basketballPlayer.id)}>Dismiss</button>
         </div>
     );
   })}
```